# Univariate Taylor expansion of a multivariate function?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation-theory

I am reading [this paper](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/weitzman/files/prices_vs_quantities.pdf) on Economics, but I am stuck in what it seems a simple 2nd order Taylor expansion.

There are two key equations:

$$C(q,\theta)$$
$$B(q,\eta)$$

These are a cost and benefit function respectively, which depend on the quantity produced, $q$. Additionally, both functions have uncertainty, which is given by $\theta$ and $\eta$ respectively.

This is the central issue and the expansion:

[image]

I can understand most of the terms of the expansions. For instance, the first term in each equation is the value of the respective function around the reference point $\hat{q}$, as the author states:

[image]

All the other terms are consistent with an univariate Taylor expansion, except for $\alpha(\theta)$ and $\beta(\eta)$. I cannot understand where they come from.

**This does not seem to be an [expansion of a multivariate series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables), but an univariate one,** as revealed by the $(q-\hat{q})$ terms. In other words, the expansion is around $\hat{q}$, and not around $(\hat{q},\hat{\theta})$. This seems to be a type of *univariate Taylor expansion of a multivariate function*, if that thing exists. I haven't seem such type of expansions anywhere.

Comment: If $C$ is a function of several variables, $\hat{q}$ is a point of the domain, and $v$ is a direction, you can Taylor expand the one-variable function$f(t) = C(\hat{q} + tv)$ into$$f(t) \approx f(0) + f'(0)t + \tfrac{1}{2}f''(0)t^{2} = C(\hat{q}) + C'(\hat{q})tv + \tfrac{1}{2}(tv)^{T}C''(\hat{q})(tv).$$Writing $q = \hat{q} + tv$, you have $tv = q - \hat{q}$. Denoting the quadratic term $\frac{1}{2}C''(\hat{q})(q - \hat{q})^{2}$ formally gives the expressions you ask about. Haven't looked at the paper itself, but I hope this is helpful.

Comment: All that is fine. But each expansion also has an extra component in the linear term, component which is not present in the quadratic term: $\alpha(\theta)$ and $\beta(\eta)$. I just can't understand where they come from. I think your equation does not show that either.

Comment: That looks like a modeling assumption (i.e., economics, not mathematics): The first two terms are stochastic, but the second is assumed constant.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see. Well, I thought to ask this in the Econ network, but I could imagine the question being dismissed as a "mathematical" question rather than economics one. Maybe I can try there.